# Hiding unavailable catalog in Databricks UI with Unity Catalog enabled Workspace

Tags: databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I have multiple workspaces attached to Unity Catalog. When I create a catalog in any workspace, by default they are available in all workspaces. If I unbind a catalog from a workspace, then in this workspace I can see that the catalog exists but I don't have access to it.

[example catalog list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCYdi.png)
Is it possible to hide those unavailable catalogs ('my_new_catalog' on the screen)

I tried to change isolation level using UI and allow this catalog to be available only in workspace where it had been created. The result I showed on the screenshot. I expected that this catalog will not appear on the list.